# Rails4 nested model validation fails

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a model Profile, which belongs to Person and Person has many emails. What's interesting is happening, when I'm creating Profile (one big form based on nested_form gem) and fill wrong email, after clicking "Create" the validation will return error message, but when I click "Create" again without any change in form I got "Couldn't find Person with ID=1002 for Profile with ID=". Somehow Person is created without profile. I don't want to create Person if associated email is wrong. I was trying different validation to avoid this error, like validates_associated, etc. Here is my code:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :contact_person
  belongs_to :person, validate: true    

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true

  validates_presence_of  :person   

  delegate :gender, :title, :first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :place_of_birth, :name, :company, :company_name, :age, :web_profiles, :main_email, :main_phone_number, :main_address, :main_web_profile, to: :person  
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  GENDER = { male: 2, female: 1}
  TITLE = { dr: 0, prof: 1, prof_dr: 2 }

  has_one     :profile
  has_many    :emails, validate: true,                class_name: 'ContactType::Email'
  has_many    :phone_numbers, validate: true,         class_name: "ContactType::PhoneNumber"
  has_many    :web_profiles, validate: true,          class_name: "ContactType::WebProfile"

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name  

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :web_profiles, allow_destroy: true
end

class ContactType::Email < ActiveRecord::Base

  EMAIL_TYPE = { work: 0, private: 1, other: 2 }

  belongs_to :person, validate: true  

  validates_format_of :address, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, message: I18n.t('simple_form.error.address_email')

  def email_type
    EMAIL_TYPE.key(read_attribute(:email_type))
  end

  def email_type=(t)
    write_attribute(:email_type, EMAIL_TYPE[t.to_sym])
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.